# Where is the VBComponents object in the Excel object model?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com-interop, extensibility

hi i am working with c# and excel-2007...
i wanted to add a macro to excel and run from c#, for which i think i need access to the VBComponents but unfortunately i cannot see it after i do the following

```
    wb.VBProject.
```

should i add any com objects? or what should i do to see the VBComponents...

i already have

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    //wb is a workbook i can see VBProject but not other components of it...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the VBIDE, looks like you have to search for the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library**. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872) for more details.

Hope these help.

Comment: i already have 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: i am using example from this site
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/create_macro_at_runtime_in_dotnet.asp

where he gets VBComponents from VBProject, but i cannot see VBComponents afte wb.VBProject. (i see nothing)
my question is how can i get VBComponents